# Naive Bayes classifier using python

Tags: python, machine-learning, bayesian, scikits, scikit-learn

I'm using scikit-learn for finding the Tf-idf weight of a document and then using the Naive
Bayesian classifier to classify the text. But the  Tf-idf weight of all words in a documents are negative except a few. But as far as I know, negative values means unimportant terms. So is it necessary to pass the whole Tf-idf values to the bayesian classifier? If we only need to pass only a few of those, how can we do it? Also how better or worse is a bayesian classifier compared to a linearSVC? Is there a better way to find tags in a text other than using Tf-idf ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a lot of questions there but I'll try to help.

As far as I remember, TF-IDF should not be a negative value. TF is the term frequency (how often a term appears in a particular document) and the inverse document frequency (# of documents in corpus / # of documents that include the term). That's then usually log weighted. We often add one to the denominator as well to avoid division by zero. Hence, the only time you would get a negative tf*idf is if the term appears in every single document of the corpus (which is not very helpful to search on as you mentioned since it doesn't add information). I would double check your algorithm.

given term t, document d, corpus c:

```
tfidf = term freq * log(document count / (document frequency + 1))
tfidf = [# of t in d] * log([#d in c] / ([#d with t in c] + 1))
```

In machine learning naive bayes and SVMs are both good tools--their quality will vary depending on the application and I've done projects where their accuracy turned out to be comparable. Naive Bayes is usually pretty easy to hack together by hand--I'd give that a shot first before venturing to SVM libraries.

I might be missing something but I'm not quite confident I know exactly what you're looking for--Happy to modify my answer.

Comment: First of all Thanks for your fast response. So if words with Tf-idf values greater than zero are taken, could that be used as tags? .

Comment: Also what is your opinion of training Bayes classifier. Is it necessary to do it using the whole document Tf-idf or can it be done using only Tf-idf values of words having higher Tf-idf values.

Comment: Well, most words in a document should not be negative, first of all. How large is your corpus? Obviously remove stopwords like "the", "an", etc before running things. Not sure what you mean by tags, but if you mean like labels for features or similar then I think that's a good approach.

Comment: Consider we have found tf-idf values of a 1000 documents. Is there any way so that we can use these weights for finding tf-idf values of new documents to be classified ?.

Comment: tf*idf is based on a term-document tuple, so unless your corpus changes you could certainly store those, perhaps in a Dict of (term,docid)=>value.

Comment: How can we use these data to train other documents ?.

Comment: Wont that require the number of documents that have been trained and the frequency of each word in the documents, rather than the tf-idf values. Correct me if I'm wrong ?. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This bug has been fixed in the master branch. Beware as the [text vectorizer API](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction) has changed a bit too to make it easier to customize the tokenization.

Comment: Is there a possible way to save the values of bayes classifier and its vocabulary in scikit, so that classification of documents would be easy ?.

Comment: With saving bayes classifier I mean word probability weights after a training session.

Comment: @jvc: you can [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) the entire classifier object in scikit-learn.

Answer (score 2):

I am interesting in this theme too.
When I am using baes classification (may be this russian article about baes algorithm can help you http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/python/120194/) I use only 20 top word of documents. I tried many values. In my exeperimental top 20 get best result.
Also I changed usual tf-idf to this:

```
def f(word):
    idf = log10(0.5 / word.df)
    if idf < 0:
        idf = 0
    return word.tf * idf
```

In this case "bad words" wieght equal 0.

Comment: This probably would just whitewash over the problem. @ogrisel notes there's a bug, which makes sense. Most words should not have negative values.

Comment: It is not whitewash. Because my wieght word's  is not classic tf-idf. And it(idf) can be negative.

Comment: Oh ok, if its a different type then.